# Python: pass list to another list but list is blank

Tags: python, excel, list, function, openpyxl

I am using python 3.7 with openpyxl. I am attempting to parse data from a worksheet to a list. In this function Originally I was pulling info directly from one spreadsheet into a list and then using openpyxl to paste into another worksheet, however I am unable to use excel filters and such, so now I am attempting to edit the information in a list. The problem is that when I attempt to parse information to that list, it shows up fine in current_data, but as I append the list I get different information, almost as if it is overwriting the list. See the function and output below. Thank you in advance.

```
def cut_sheet_up(wsn, nws, output_log):
    x=0
    ws = wb[wsn]
    current_data = []
    for rowOfCellObjects in ws.iter_rows(min_row=0, min_col=0):
        current_data.clear()
        for cellObj in rowOfCellObjects:
            if cellObj.value is None:
                current_data.append('')
                # print causes ' value in front of string
            elif isinstance(cellObj.value, datetime) or isinstance(cellObj.value, time):
                current_data.append(cellObj.value)
            else:
                current_data.append(str(cellObj.value))
        nws.append(current_data)
        if wb[wsn] == wb['output_log']:
            x+=1
            print(current_data)
            output_log.append(current_data)
        else:
            pass
```

The first 150 lines or so are print as actual information under current_data, and the rest of the lines print as the following below.

```
['foo', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

In the worksheet I am passing the information to I receive correct data as well using the current function. However when I do a print(output_log) after the function I get all 1500 lines as

```
['foo', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're clearing the list inside the for loop, theres no need to reuse the same list here, so just initialize it within the for loop instead of clearing it

```
for rowOfCellObjects in ws.iter_rows(min_row=0, min_col=0):
    current_data = []
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are re-using the same list in each iteration of the loop.

`current_data.clear()` does clear the list, but this is the same **reference** that got appended earlier.

To solve your problem, simply move the `current_data = []` (line 4) inside the for loop and remove the `current_data.clear()` statement.

EDIT: Here's a short example to demonstrate the difference between a *value* and a *reference*.

```
my_list = []  # my_list is a variable that is pointing to a list
other_list = my_list  # other_list is a second variable that is pointing to the same list
my_list.append(1)
print(my_list)  # Prints out "[1]"
print(other_list)  # Also print out "[1]"
```

We say that both variables reference the same instance (the list). What happens if we assign a new list to `my_list`:

```
my_list = []
print(my_list)  # Prints out "[]"
print(other_list)  # Still prints out "[1]"
```

They now refer to different lists altogether.

Related to this is the concept of "pass by value" and "pass by reference", which you may find useful to know.

Comment: this too is a good answer because I do not understand the concept of reference in this respect well and now I will research it.

Comment: An example is usually a good way to show the difference. EDIT: Woops already pressed enter there. I'll write a short example.

Comment: I edited the answer to hopefully better explain the issue.